# Run python script from another python script but not as an child process

Tags: python, unix, process

Is it possible to run a python script from another python script without wating for termination.

Parent process will terminate immediately after creation of child process.

I tried:

```
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "main.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and also:

```
os.system(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the other Python script has a `main` method, you could simply in you code call that other script:

```
import main
...
exit(main.main())
```

But here the other script executes in the context of calling script. If you want to avoid it, you could use the `os.exec...` functions, by launching a new Python interpretor:

```
import os
...
os.execl(sys.executable, "python", 'main.py')
```

The exec family functions will replace (under Unix-Linux) the current Python interpretor with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `&` to start script in background:

```
import os

os.system('/path/to/script.sh &')

exit()
```

In this case launched shell script will continue working even after main Python script exits.
But keep in mind that it can cause zombie processes appearance in our system.